# Loading local images in React Native Image component

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i'm working on an application with react native on android. i would like to put some Image components on the screen and load them with some local image files. can someone provide the directory (relative to the project's root directory) in which i should place my files ? the docs don't seem to provide any useful information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the example here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#adding-static-resources-to-your-android-app

> Adding Static Resources to your Android app  Add your images as bitmap
>   drawables to the android project (/android/app/src/main/res).
>   To provide different resolutions of your assets, check out using
>   configuration qualifiers. Normally, you will want to put your assets
>   in the following directories (create them under res if they don't
>   exist):
>
> - drawable-mdpi (1x)
> - drawable-hdpi (1.5x)
> - drawable-xhdpi (2x)
> - drawable-xxhdpi (3x)
>
> If you're missing a resolution for your asset,
>   Android will take the next best thing and resize it for you.
>
> NOTE: App build required for new resources Any time you add a new
>   resource to your drawables you will need to re-build your app by
>   running `react-native run-android` before you can use it - reloading the
>   JS is not enough. This process is currently being improved, a much
>   better workflow will be available shortly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728163/anyone-success-in-using-local-image-in-react-native-for-android do you know the proper way to generate the apk? Because I couldn't render the local image after that :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't and don't have the time to look into it right now. Maybe ask a new question on here? Good luck!