# Anyone success in using local image in react native for Android?

Tags: android, image, react-native

I'm using react native 0.14.2. I asked this question on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4084) but that repo is overwhelming by too many issues. Hope I can find the answer here.

So here is the project structure:

```
android-project
+---app
|   \---src
|       \---main
|           \---assets
|           \---java
|           \---res
+---reactnative
|   \---assets
|       \---image@1x.png
|       \---image@2x.png
|       \---image@3x.png
----index.android.js
```

Here's the code to show the image:

```
<Image
    source={require('./reactnative/assets/image.png')}
    resizeMode='contain'
    style={styles.image} />
```

The above code works fine when running together with localhost `react-native start`. But it doesn't work after bundling react native resources into the apk:

```
react-native bundle --platform android -dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
--bundle-output app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
--assets-dest app/src/main/res/
```

Here's the output:

```
android-project
+---app
|   \---src
|       \---main
|           \---assets
|               \---index.android.bundle
|           \---java
|           \---res
|               \---drawable-xxxhdpi
|                   \---reactnative_assets_image1.png
|               \---drawable-xxhdpi
|                   \---reactnative_assets_image1.png
|               \---drawable-xhdpi
|                   \---reactnative_assets_image1.png
|               \---drawable-mdpi
|                   \---reactnative_assets_image1.png
```

Is it the right way to generate the apk with react native? Please troubleshoot. Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade instructions here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

Comment: Are you on Windows? Seems like the new assets system broke some things. If so you might wanna check https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4207 for a solution.

Comment: @DaveSibiski I started with 0.14.2 directly for an existing project, so I don't think I need to upgrade anything.

Comment: @Almouro I'm using MacOS

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: Should be fixed in the latest version

Answer (score 1):

when using `require()` in standard JS, the path given is relative, therefore any paths given need to be relative to the file you're requiring them in. THe best way to do this is not to have them inside the 'android' and 'ios' directories, but have a seperate one with your apps JS code in, and store the images in there, that way the paths will be much shorter, and not different per OS.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look visit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#adding-static-resources-to-your-android-app for you query, basically you set up you code like 
`<Image source={require('./ res/check.png')} />` using the JS files and putting your images in the drawable folders e.g `check.png in android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi`

Comment: You can double check my question. I could run the app just fine using localhost. But after generating the assets and bundling the js file I couldn't see any image.